# Please suggest me a basic layout to use, other than the GridBag layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

OK I have `a panel`, and I want to place `two panels on to it`, `left and right`, such that the **right panel should be double the width of the left side panel.**

I want to add a menu to the left side panel, and the details of the selected item will appear in the right side panel.

**Secondly, the size of the panels and their components should increase proportionately when the window is expanded (If any methods can be used for the purpose, please suggest!)**

I did try to use the GridBagLayout but I think I have not yet been able to grasp it well. So please suggest the simplest layout manager which can serve my purpose.

---

**EDIT:- PROBLEMS WITH WHAT I HAD TRIED WITH THE GRIDBAG**

```
//Set Layout
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c= new GridBagConstraints();

        //Set Layout constraints of components and add them to the MainPanel
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.weightx=0.5;
        c.insets= new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(iListPanel);
        iListPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Check") );

        GridBagConstraints c1= new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.weightx=1;
        c.insets= new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(iDetailsPanel);
        iDetailsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Check"));
```

[image]

Comment: Downvoter, please say why you are downvoting, otherwise there is no chance of improvement!

Comment: Even if you don't want to customize the `weighty` proportions you should put a value other than the default `0.0` because 0.0 will clump the components to the center of its cells, with the extra space outside of them (and you generaly want to give the extra space to the component).

Comment: @DSquare Thank you for this piece of information (since I have been facing a lot of clumping together of components since I have started reading up on GridBag layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the layout managers that come with Java, I think GridBagLayout is the simplest one that will do that. It's worth the time to learn it, because it's about the only layout manager that's halfway-competent. This should do it:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c;

JPanel left = new JPanel();
left.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Left"));
c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = c.BOTH;
panel.add(left, c);

JPanel right = new JPanel();
right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Right"));
c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 2;
c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = c.BOTH;
panel.add(right, c);
```

However, from the description of your problem, it sounds like [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) will serve you better for this. It's a ready-made component to do more-or-less what you're asking, and has a user-resizeable separator as well. An example:

```
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane();
pane.setResizeWeight(1/3f); // right will be twice size of left

JPanel left = new JPanel();
left.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Left"));
pane.setLeftComponent(left);

JPanel right = new JPanel();
right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Right"));
pane.setRightComponent(right);
```

---

Edit: The problem with your original code is that it does not *use* the constraints.

```
add(iListPanel);
```

should be:

```
add(iListPanel, c);
```

and likewise for `iDetailsPanel`.

Comment: Thank you, but before even running it, I want to ask about gridx and gridy constraints? I think you forgot them

Comment: @Zarah I ignored them. The default values (`RELATIVE`) will work.

Comment: Thank you so very much! That solved my problem, and I did understand your code, but I think I'll need some experience to get a grip on the GridBag..

Comment: I have a follow up question from your code of the splitpane, from this statement: `pane.setResizeWeight(1/3f);` According to the documentation, it takes a double value. I was assuming that it's something like _"Out of 3 total parts, 1 is taken by the left component, so 2 parts will be left to be taken by the right component."_ **But what is f?** (if this is hexadecimal, 3f equals 63 - more confused.)

Comment: @Zarah Your assumption about the parts is correct. `f` simply indicates `float`. Without the `f`, 1 and 3 are both integers, so 1/3 is 0, rather than 0.3333....

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a BorderLayout.

```
panel.add(panelLeft,"West");
panel.add(panelRight,"East");
```

North, South and Center is also available

Comment: Thank you, but please tell me how will the right panel's width be set to double the width of the left panel.

Comment: If your components are bigger it should set automatically

Comment: The components will be added dynamically!

Comment: Then you can set the size of the panel

Comment: If I set the size of the panel, it won't increase proportionately when the window is expanded (mentioned that in the question), what will I do about that?